# Find the lone number

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, logic

I’m trying to search through an array and print out the only number within it which doesn’t have a pair, so in this case '4'.

The result keeps coming up as 2 so even though I feel I have the logic correct, I am definitely overlooking something.

I've been trying to solve this for a while and keep getting stuck

Many thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    int foundNum = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter !=n) {
        int i = 0;
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1]) {
            foundNum = arr[i];
        } else {
            arr[i] = arr[i+2];
        }
        counter += 1;
    }
    std::cout << foundNum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your logic seems completely wrong in my eyes. You don't update `i`. Is the update of the array intended? It seems you should explain how to do the task in a plain language (like English) first and then write code that represents your explanation.

Comment: If your goal is to "search", then what are you trying to accomplish by modifying the array?

Comment: 1st iter: `arr[0] == arr[1]`, so `arr[i] = arr[i+2]` is executed and `arr[0]` is set to `2` (`arr[2]`) 2nd iter and later: `arr[0] != arr[1]`, so `foundNum = arr[i]` is executed and `foundNum` is set to `2` (`arr[0]`).

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply. I just want to search through the array comparing an element with the one next to it, if they are the same, to move onto the next number which would be I + 2 positions away, and do the same again, if there is no matching number, set that to foundNum and then that would be the output

Comment: " arr[i] = arr[i+2];" does not "move to the next number". It looks to me like what needs to be done here [is have the shown code reviewed by your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and then follow your rubber duck's instructions.

Comment: That is a great suggestion, although, I'm still new to C++ and I understand what I want to do, it's just actually implementing it which im struggling with. I thought the loop would begin comparing again at arr[I+2], although you're correct in that I've accidentally modified the array instead, which is causing the issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have `counter`, so you should use that to determine the index to inspect instead of the new variable `i`.

Also to move the search position to `+2` position, you should add `2` to the loop variable instead of modifying the array.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void){
    int arr[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    int foundNum = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while(counter !=n) {
        if (counter + 1 >= n || arr[counter] != arr[counter + 1]) {
            foundNum = arr[counter];
            counter += 1;
        } else {
            counter += 2;
        }
    }
    std::cout << foundNum;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: ```arr[counter + 1]``` will be out of bounds of the array when counter == n-1

Comment: @NullPointer It should be prevented by the condition `counter + 1 < n`

Comment: The condition still gets checked....? You don't think that it checks the first condition in the statement and then nothing after that... do you?

Comment: Brilliant thank you, just as a pointer - this only worked when removing `counter + 1 < n` from the `if` condition

Comment: @NullPointer Ah, I found a bug and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all the remaining numbers except the lone number occur in pairs, it is very easy to do with an [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation.

And xor an a pair is 0. So if you go through the entire array all pairs when xor'ed result in 0.

XOR with a 0 results in the same number itself. So when all numbers cancel through their own duplicate, the lone number xor's with the resulting 0 to remain as the answer.

Code :

```
int main(){
    int arr[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr), a = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) a = a ^ arr[i];
    std::cout << "Found the lone number : " << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how this works fully but this is a clean solution and is really helpful. Definitely something to look into, thank you.

Comment: @Severin12121 please read upon the XOR operation, and work through the array you will get it.